# How to check if i already retweeted a tweet with tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I am trying to create a bot to retweet tweets that have a certain keyword in them. The code until now is this:

```
import time

import tweepy
import config

# Search/ Like/ Retweet


def get_client():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN,
                           consumer_key=config.CONSUMER_KEY,
                           consumer_secret=config.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                           access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, )
    return client


def search_tweets(query):
    client = get_client()

    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)

    tweet_data = tweets.data

    results = []

    if tweet_data is not None and len(tweet_data) > 0:
        for tweet in tweet_data:
            obj = {'id': tweet.id, 'text': tweet.text}
            results.append(obj)
    else:
        return ''

    return results


client = get_client()

tweets = search_tweets('#save the earth')


for tweet in tweets:
    client.retweet(tweet["id"])
```

It works as intended , but i want to create an if statement on the for loop to check if i already retweed that tweet or not. If not to retweet it. I cant find how to do this. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

#### EDIT

###### an answer relevant for Tweepy V2

---

unfortunately, the solution to your problem in the new version is a bit more "pricy".

you can get the list of users that retweeted a tweet using `Client.get_retweeters(tweet_id)`
and then check your client id against this list.
that might take you more resources than the previous solution, but that's what tweepy gives us.

you can read more on [tweepy docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#retweets)

---

using the tweet id and your user key you can check if you retweeted.

```
# fetching the status
status = api.get_status(id)
      
# fetching the retweeted attribute
retweeted = status.retweeted
```

your code would be this:

```
import time

import tweepy
import config

# Search/ Like/ Retweet


def get_client():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=config.BEARER_TOKEN,
                           consumer_key=config.CONSUMER_KEY,
                           consumer_secret=config.CONSUMER_SECRET,
                           access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                           access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, )
    return client


def search_tweets(query):
    client = get_client()

    tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results=10)

    tweet_data = tweets.data

    results = []

    if tweet_data is not None and len(tweet_data) > 0:
        for tweet in tweet_data:
            status = tweepy.api(client.access_token).get_status(tweet.id)
            if status.retweeted:
                continue
            else:
                obj = {'id': tweet.id, 'text': tweet.text}
                results.append(obj)
    else:
        return ''

    return results


client = get_client()

tweets = search_tweets('#save the earth')


for tweet in tweets:
    client.retweet(tweet["id"])
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\timi_\PycharmProjects\VinuWizard\searchtweets.py", line 43, in <module>
    tweets = search_tweets('#vinu')
  File "C:\Users\timi_\PycharmProjects\VinuWizard\searchtweets.py", line 29, in search_tweets
    status = tweepy.api(client.access_token).get_status(tweet.id)
TypeError: 'API' object is not callable

Comment: im using tweepy auth v2 , tweepy.api doesnt work on this unfortunatelly